# Why the data on the components is not updated when opening another page ? (Vue.JS 2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-resource

I have 2 component

Component first like this : http://pastebin.com/M8Q3au0B

Because the code is a bit much, I use a pastebin

From component first, it call component two

component two is like this :

```
<template>
    <span class="rating">
        <template v-for="item in items">
            <label class="radio-inline input-star" :class="{'is-selected': ((starValue >= item.value) && starValue !== null)}">
                <input type="radio" class="input-rating"v-model="starValue">
            </label>
        </template>
    </span>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {'star': null,'store': null,'id': null}, 
        data() {
            return {
                items: [{value: 5},{value: 4},{value: 3},{value: 2},{value: 1}],
                starValue: this.star
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

For example, I have two page

When in the page one, the results worked well

When I click page two, username, updated_at, comments also worked well

But, on the rating does not work. It does not update

How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you add component `StarRating` also, is it not being updated in this component?

Comment: @Saurabh, I had add it. Component two is component `StarRating`. Yes, It is not being updated in the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see `list` is being populated asynchronously, so it will not be available to `starRating` component when it first mounts. to get the value when it is populated, you may have to put a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on it like this:

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: {'star': null,'store': null,'id': null}, 
        data() {
            return {
                items: [{value: 5},{value: 4},{value: 3},{value: 2},{value: 1}],
                starValue: this.star
            }
        },
        watch : {
           star: function(newVal) {
                this.starValue = newVal
           }
        }  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Great. I works. Thanks. You are the master vue.js :)